# How can I re-size a popup image gallery as per the display size using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, gallery, lightbox

I created a simple image gallery popup using w3school's light box examples in [How TO - Lightbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp)

The issue I'm facing is, if the image size is very large, the popup will show with a scroll. how can I resize any sized image as per the browser width and height without shrinking the image? You can see a simple example just opening a 4k image on chrome. It will automatically adjust as per the browser size with aspect ratio. I want the same.

Comment: This is the gallery i used   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

Comment: add your codes please

Answer (score 0):

You easly can call all of your images in css and set the "max-width" to "inherit". So it inherits from its parent element or you can set the max-width to a fixed value.

Comment: could be comment rather than answer

Comment: Hi thanks for the replay the issue i faced is if the image height is very large or larger than the display the popup will show with a scroll i don't want that i want to re-size water ever size image based on the view port just like the light box Jquery does in javascript